# iPhone stuck "Removing iCloud Data..." after iCloud sign out

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I have an iPhone 5C and have logged out of iCloud (in order to test in App Purchasing on an App under development).

The 'phone indicated "Removing iCloud data...", which seems reasonable, but it has been stuck like that for around 30 minutes now, which does not. There is not that much iCloud data on the 'phone.

Pressing Home closes settings and other apps can be run. But the logout process does not appear to be complete as the In App Purchase test does not ask for an account name, just a password. Reopening Settings just brings back the "Removing iCloud data..." indication.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After an hour I decided there was something clearly wrong, so this is what I did to resolve it:

1. Powered down (long press on the top button, slide to power off),
2. Powered up and entered password,
3. Opened Settings (I appeared to still be still logged in to iCloud, but iCloud was off - it seems that things were just half completed in the original sign out),
4. Signed Out of iCloud again (this time it finished almost immediately).

The In-App-Purchase test then worked fine.

Comment: This did not work. Many, many hours passed. Powering down and trying again multiple times did NOT work. I will add my own answer if it lets me, which is to go on another iOS device logged into the account and ask it to log out or the problem device from there, and then to reset

Comment: This worked for me. Turn off then on, sign out, this time it took only 1 minute.

Comment: Worked for me in 2023 on an iPhone SE.... hey that rhymes, twice! (iPhone SE 2nd gen 2020)

Answer (score 3):

What I did was to:

1. follow what @Ali Beadle's approach
2. from another iOS device, go to settings and delete the iCloud Backup for this old device

After 2) was done, the signing out is immediately done.

Answer (score 1):

If other answers do not work (it was stuck for me for many hours, with repeated attempts to restart and try again), then the only think to do is the following:

1. Log in to the same iCloud account  in another device
2. from there to go to the iCloud settings where you should see a list of all the devices you are logged in to.
3. Select the problem device that is hung logging out and ask it to log out.

This seems to get the problem device logged out.

4. Now, back on the logged out device that was previously hung, try to reset (to factory settings). It will still prompt you that it is erasing data, but it finally seems to work.

(note, if you can't get out of the stuck "Removing iCloud data" state before doing step 4, then simply 'kill' the system preferences app by double-clicking on the home button (or swiping up diagonally on face-id devices) and then swiping up).